# Not able to access a file created by a docker container from another container?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, containers, devops

For the current working scenario I have two containers which need to share data. First container is a flask application which does some work on data and creates log file. While the other container is R shiny app which serves as a status dashboard for the application, and also when needed user can also directly view the log file by providing a key on the dashboard itself. Here my issue is that while accessing log file from shiny dashboard container permission denied error is being thrown. I have mounted same volume on both the containers also tried giving owner permission to shiny app container but still container could not access the file, while I can access the same file on host location. Is there something I am missing which needs authorization of shared volumes among containers or is there is any issue with the shiny app. Please provide possible solutions to it.

### Required Files

Docker-compose files.
Docker-compose file for application:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: mlengine
    networks:
      - network1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileEngine
    volumes:
      - ./logs_n_status:/root/project/logs_n_status
      #- logData:/root/project/logs_n_status
    ports:
      - 7011:3000
    expose:
      - "3000"
```

Docker-compose file for shiny dashboard:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  dashboard:
    container_name: dashboard
    image: mlapidashboard
    networks:
      - network1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileRTD
    volumes:
      - /home/mlprod/dmda/testAPI/logs_n_status:/root/project/logs_n_status
      #--volumes-from Container4:ro
      #- logData:/root/project/logs_n_status:ro
    ports:
      - 9000:3838
networks:
    network1:
#volumes:
#    logData:
```

DockerfileEngine:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get --fix-missing update && apt-get --fix-broken install && apt-get install -y poppler-utils && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr && \
    apt-get install -y libtesseract-dev && apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev && ldconfig && apt-get install -y python3.6 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

WORKDIR /root/
RUN mkdir /root/project
WORKDIR /root/project
RUN mkdir /root/project/processingDirectory

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY ./xxxx xxxx

RUN python3 ./nltkDownloader.py
CMD ["gunicorn", "-t", "999999", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3000", "wsgi:app"]
```

DockerfileDashboard:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:3.5.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libv8-3.14-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev -y &&\
  mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('mongolite', 'dplyr', 'jsonlite', 'ggplot2', 'grid', 'gridExtra', 'DT', 'data.table', 'httr', 'shiny'))"

RUN mkdir /root/project
RUN mkdir /root/project/logs_n_status

COPY ./RealTimeDashboard /srv/shiny-server/RealTimeDashboard

RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/
RUN chmod -R 777 /root/project/logs_n_status

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Comment: how do you start these containers? can you also share the Dockerfiles?

Comment: Give minimal example please.

Comment: @Stefano I have added the docker-compose files(only the required part) and instead of using the docker-compose file for dashboard I was also using docker run command to start the container

Comment: @atline please consider the edits

Comment: Can you add portions of the Dockerfiles? Like what base image you're using, did you change the USER in there and so on?

Comment: @Stefano Done the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rocker/shiny` uses the `shiny` as a user ([src](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/blob/master/shiny-server.sh)) while the other application produces logs using `root` (and they might have special privileges set).

The shiny user has a UID = 999. 
How to extract it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm rocker/shiny bash
root@536f2edc5768:/usr/bin# su - shiny
$ id
uid=999(shiny) gid=999(shiny) groups=999(shiny)
```

To fix your issues, I'd change the DockerfileEngine to look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get --fix-missing update && apt-get --fix-broken install && apt-get install -y poppler-utils && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr && \
    apt-get install -y libtesseract-dev && apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev && ldconfig && apt-get install -y python3.6 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 999 theuser
RUN mkdir -p /project \
    && chown -R theuser /project

USER theuser
WORKDIR /project

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN mkdir /project/processingDirectory

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY --chown=theuser ./xxxx xxxx

RUN python3 ./nltkDownloader.py
CMD ["gunicorn", "-t", "999999", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3000", "wsgi:app"]
```

Make sure that the mounted folder is writable by both container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stefano. I am curious if we can do exactly reverse of the same process, or instead of using the `rocker/shiny` base image we can install shiny server on an ubuntu image itself. What could the positive or negative consequences of doing so.

Comment: You can rewrite the content of the shiny-server.sh to use root but I'm not sure if it'd work and it's always a security issue. Same story goes for the "DockerfileEngine" image. Using root in there is never a good idea (when it comes to security). Concerning the idea of using shiny on the host, I'm forced to use a similar setup and it's not fun at all (especially if you plan to have communication between the container and host)

Comment: I am getting the following error while building the image and running the container. Error is in main app where I have created a new user.  ```ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"gunicorn\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Try to enter the container using `docker run --user root -it --rm $imageName bash`, check what's `gunicorn` path and fix the CMD

Comment: Thanks @Stefano, dashboard container is now able to read data created by the application container. Issue has been resolved